# undefined method 'get post' in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

[image]

> Me aparece un error al invocar el metodo del incoming request class . sin embargo me hace bien el post.

Answer (score 0):

Ese mensaje también me lo envía en VS Code pero funciona sin problemas. No es un error como tal sino que IntelliSense no está detectando los métodos.

Funciona porque la clase que implementa esa interfaz tiene los métodos que estás buscando.